# TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'JpegImageFile'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The following code is giving me an error:

```
def save(self):
    self.filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File ", "", "JPEG(*.JPEG *.jpeg *.JPG *.jpg)")
    img =Image.open(self.filePath)
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO DriverInfo(driverImg)VALUES(?)", repr(memoryview(img)))
    conn.commit()
```

The error is:

`TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'JpegImageFile'`

Answer (score 5):

As the error message suggests, a [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memory-views) expects to receives raw bytes. To get the bytes that make up the image, do this:

```
from io import BytesIO
img = Image.open('1x1.jpg')

# Create a buffer to hold the bytes
buf = BytesIO()

# Save the image as jpeg to the buffer
img.save(buf, 'jpeg')

# Rewind the buffer's file pointer
buf.seek(0)

# Read the bytes from the buffer
image_bytes = buf.read()

# Close the buffer
buf.close()
```

Or more succintly:

```py
with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    img.save(buf, 'jpeg')
    image_bytes = buf.getvalue()
```